# Eclipse-cdt - include files issue (resets after change)

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I have a problem with eclipse-cdt (latest version).
I dont use any toolchain here, just simple makefile.
There is no problem with building - everything works but eclipse annoys me when i change something in my code.

For example:
[some random code which builds - no warnings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wf82c.png)
and after adding one line [everything is red :( - but code still builds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ad0xV.png). but when i save and close eclipse and open i dont have all these warnings.

I have added include path in **Properties -> c/c++ general -> preprocessor include paths, macros**

How can i fix this?

Comment: What do the warnings say...?

Comment: Symbol ... could not be resolved @immibis

Comment: First thing to test is that the includes themselves work. If you cannot ctrl-click on the include line and it takes you to the expected file, then the indexer is not configured correctly to find the needed includes.